# How to validate zipcode using ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to prevent user from entering '00000' in the zip code field. Currently, `ng-pattern` allows 5 digits in the ZIP code. I am not sure how to construct the expression so as to prevent the user from entering all zeros.

Comment: What is your current expression? Include it in your question

Comment: Try using a [negative-lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), such as: `ng-pattern="/^(?!00000)\d{5}$/"`?